# Find the poles of $f$ at $z=2πik$?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

> Let $f(z)= \dfrac{z}{ (1-e^{z} ) \sin z}$ then the poles of $f$ at $z=2πik$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ $k \neq 0$are of order $1$ or $2$?

\begin{align}
\lim_{z \to 2πik} (z-2πik)^2 \dfrac{z}{ (1-e^{z}) \sin z } &= \lim_{z \to 2πik} \dfrac{z}{ \dfrac{1-e^{z}}{z-2πik} \dfrac{\sin z}{z-2πik}} \\
&= 2πik \neq 0
\end{align}

so it is a pole of order $2$ . Is it correct?

Comment: What happens for $k = 0$?

Comment: for k=0 it is a simple pole

Comment: it appeared in one of the competitive exams and the answer key says those are the poles of order 1

Comment: The poles are all simple. I think you are confused here by thinking $\sin(2\pi i k) = 0$, but this is not so. It is true that $1 - e^{2\pi i k} = 0$, but since only this term is zero and it yields a zero of order one we get a pole of order one

Answer (score 1):

Here , $\forall k \in \mathbb Z$, $\quad e^z-1=0\implies e^z=1=e^{2k\pi i}\implies z=2k\pi i\quad$ are poles.

Now $\lim_{z \to 2k\pi i}(z-2k\pi i)f(z)$

$=\lim_{z \to 2k\pi i} \frac{z(z - 2k\pi i)}{(1-e^z)\sin z}$ $\quad (\frac{0}{0}\text{form})$

$=\lim_{z \to 2k\pi i}\frac{2z - 2k\pi i}{(1-e^z)\cos z -e^z \sin z}$, which gives a finite value.

$\implies z=2k\pi i$ is a simple pole.

---

> A **simple pole** of an analytic function $f(z)$ is a pole of order one. That is, $(z-z_0)f(z)$ is an analytic function at the pole $z=z_0$.
>
> In other word, for $f(z)$ has pole at  $z=z_1 \in \mathbb C$, $$\lim_{z \to z_1} f(z)= \infty$$
>
> For simple pole at $z=z_1 \in \mathbb C$, $$\lim_{z \to z_1} (z-z_1)f(z) \qquad \text{is finite.}$$